# How to put a full-width front cover page on a Tufte-class document?

Tags: tufte

I would like to put a full width picture on a front cover page using the Tufte-Latex class. How can I do it? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany, justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\titleimage}
\savebox{\titleimage}{\includegraphics[height=15\baselineskip]{garden.jpg}}

\title[Hyper Simple]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
A title \par \par \vspace{1cm}
  \usebox{\titleimage}}
\author{My name}
\publisher{Exhibition Catalog}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
% r.3 full title page
\maketitle
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{fullwidth}...\end{fullwidth}`?

Comment: Thanks! But, where have I to put that command if I want the picture to be in fullwidth?

Comment: What do you mean? Like [this](http://hastebin.com/kanifakuya.tex)?

Comment: I am searching for a way to have a full-width front cover page whose the picture covers entirely the page as for a book.